# closed form expression for an infinite sum

Tags: special-functions, closed-form

Is there any closed form expression for the infinite sum $\sum_{n≥0}q^{n^2}u^n$ where both q and n are variables and $n \in N∪0$ ?

Answer (score 2):

No. See the [Jacobi theta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theta_function).